# How do you find the vehicle manufacture date?

Tags: ford, brake-calipers, expedition

03 Ford Expedition xlt 4wd 5.4L - I have no data plate on driver door! Where would I find another one data plate at? Need a new front driver side brake caliper and part store asked me if I knew the date that it was stopped manufactured.

Comment: I see what you're saying ... it appears the dividing line was between June and July of 2002. If you give your VIN to a Ford dealership, they should be able to look up when it was manufactured.

Comment: A few thoughts: (1) is this information available on the car's registration paperwork? (i.e V5 if you're UK based, pink slip if you're US based). (2) Does this information come up when you search for your vehicle by registration number when obtaining a quote for insurance? (3) Does this information come up when searching for parts for your vehicle on motor factor websites?

Comment: Ford has a website that you can put your VIN into and get the complete build details, see http://www.etis.ford.com/vehicleSelection.do : gave me full details of my car...